# google+ pick wrong image in dialog when I share

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to make a button share google+ with title, description and image. Everything works fine but only image that google+ pick wrong.
Here my code:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="{image}" />
```

After that I test and  know that Google+ will pick image with largest size in your page.
Do you have any solution?

Comment: There are a number of factors that could cause issues. Without a link to a live example it'll be hard to make any suggestions.

Comment: Same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003451/google-plus-share-url-not-showing-featured-image-title-and-description-few-days . Not working :(