# Google Plus share URL not showing featured image, title and description few days ago

Tags: url, google-plus, share, rich-snippets

I have URL:

```
http://www.racunalo.com/homtom-ht3-pro-s-posebnom-maskom-i-cijenom-za-majcin-dan-u-prodaji-na-lightintheboxu/
```

The source code is O.K. The data is valid for Google Rich Snippets and so Twitter and Open Graph.

The problem is that if I share the above URL on Google Plus (via share button or manual) the featured image, title and description are not showing up.

The problem occured few days ago. We did not chancged the code. It just happend as it was similar problem with Facebook Open Graph few weeks before.

Href data on anchor for sharing:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.racunalo.com%2Fhomtom-ht3-pro-s-posebnom-maskom-i-cijenom-za-majcin-dan-u-prodaji-na-lightintheboxu%2F&t=Homtom+HT3+Pro+s+posebnom+maskom+i+cijenom+za+Maj%C4%8Din+dan+u+prodaji+na+Lightintheboxu
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It was working good, but now it does not :(

Comment: Maybe some updates from Google? Or the domain is blocked?